# Syntax error on class definition

Tags: c++

Eclipse says : a function definition is not allowed before token '{' (at lines of the implementation)

What am I missing?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    class MainButton {
        int a;
    public:
        void pressed();
        void released();
    };

    void MainButton::pressed() {
        cout<<"Button pressed";
    }

    void MainButton::released(){
        cout<<"Button released";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to define a class in a function, in this case `int main()`. You need to move your class definition out of the scope of this function.

Answer (score 0):

Your class definition & implementation should be outside the main method:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MainButton {
    int a;
public:
    void pressed();
    void released();
};

void MainButton::pressed() {
    cout<<"Button pressed";
}

void MainButton::released(){
    cout<<"Button released";
}

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

This is because the class is not part of just the main method, but the whole program (other functions should be able to access it).

To use it, you could do:

```
int main(){
    MagicButton mb = new MagicButton();
    mb.pressed();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define the methods in that way.

The only way you can define the pressed() and released() methods inside the main() function is to define the methods inline to the class.   Your other option is to move the entire definition of the class outside of the main function().